# Visual Basic 2010_Check If the user has completed saying the voice command

Tags: vb.net

Hope you are all doing fine. I have working on a sound recorder programme. This works fine and also able t play the recorded sound.

But I want to check if the user has completed the sentence or recoding and then I would want to press "enter key" to start another procedure.

Below is my code - you cann also tell if there are alternate ways like using the "speech.recognizer" or "synthesys" in visual basic I will try that too.

Public Class Form1

```
Private Declare Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias "mciSendStringA" (ByVal lpstrCommand As String, _

                                                                               ByVal lpstrReturnString As String, ByVal uReturnLength As Integer, _

                                                                               ByVal hwndCallback As Integer) As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' record from microphone

    mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0)

    mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0)

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    ' stop  and save

    mciSendString("save recsound c:\record.wav", "", 0, 0)

    mciSendString("close recsound", "", 0, 0)

End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    ' play audio

    My.Computer.Audio.Play("c:\record.wav", AudioPlayMode.Background)

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I have removed the vb6 tag, since your code clearly is vb.net

Answer (score 0):

I know that theres a way to get the audio level from the Windows media API , but its too difficut and i can't find it . You should check the **[NAudio.dll](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio)** library . Its the most equipped audio library for .Net .

Then you will need to get the audio level from the same device you are recording with .
Add a Timer that continuosly checks it and it should be pretty easy from this point .